# Kernel: Intercept listen call with module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, socket, system-calls

I am writing an application that will detect any application calling `listen(2)` to open a socket for incoming connections and look up with a table of rules. It is much like ApplicationFirewall in macOS. So my primary approach is to override the `listen` call using some loadable kernel module.
Is it possible in linux, provided syscall table is readonly in kernel above 2.6?
What else approach is preferable?

Answer (score 1):

The preferable way is probably to use eBPF, see for instance;

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003805/can-ebpf-modify-the-return-value-or-parameters-of-a-syscall/

Don't let the "Packet Filter" part fool you, BPF is not only about packet filtering any more. It has a quite steep learning curve but it's worth it.

Comment: eBPF can modify call from vm, but I'm asking for a solution to modify system-wide calls, be it any program on a system.